# Changing HTTP URL Port

Tags: wp-config

I have worked on wordpress site in localhost:8080, after migrating to hosting server it is still using the port 8080. I have changed it in database - wp_options to 80 and added

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.bestitest.zz.vc:80/wordpress/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.bestitest.zz.vc:80/wordpress/');
```

in wp-config.php , but it still does not work.

Is there any other ways to fix it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "it does not work" is not enough information to help you, we need : 
1: what you have done (this is ok), 
2: what is the result you have now, 
3: what is the result you were waiting for

Comment: As you see there are links defined in the code, if you navigate to them you will see the result, and expectation is self explaining, port would be 80 instead of 8080

Comment: try without `:80` at all places, just `http://www.bestitest.zz.vc/wordpress/`