# Configure WordPress to listen on a port other than 80

Tags: redirect, navigation, wp-config, server, http

Similar to [changing](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/241734/63107) localhost parameters, how do I serve web pages externally through a port other than port 80?

Also similar to configuring Apache to [listen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3940909/262852) to an alternate port.

Of course, the navigation should keep to the specified port and not revert to port 80.

Comment: Have you tried changing the site URL to add a port number? I assume you've already adjusted your web server so that pages are served on that port?

Comment: This is done by configuring your web server to use another port to serve up the pages. And not a WP development question, which will probably earn you a downvote (by others). Better to search this question on the Webmasters stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TomJNowell I haven't set this up yet, so asking before I dive in.

Comment: @RickHellewell hmm, as I read the FAQ it relates to `server configuration for WordPress` does it not?

Comment: Well, maybe @Thufir . But some people around here get excitable about any question that doesn't relate to "WP Development". Not me; I'll chime in on any question that I feel that I can answer if the question has anything to do with WP. But I won't be surprised if I see downvotes on the question... or holds.